# Using Ember.ListView with Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What's the most correct way to use [Ember list view](http://emberjs.com/list-view/) with ember-cli?

The docs still show the `{{#collection}}` helper, and even though that works, [that helper has been deprecated](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_collection).

I tried using `{{#view 'list-view'}}`, and it didn't throw any errors, but it also didn't work. I believe it didn't render the `itemView`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tackle whether it should use `collection` or `view`, but I did find a way to load `list-view` into an `ember-cli` project (when `ember-cli` is at version 0.0.40 or less).

I submitted the solution as an [Ember-CLI pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view/pull/147).  Since it's a version-specific solution, I won't be surprised if they don't merge it, but it might be a "magnet" for even better solutions.

Look in my proposed **[README](https://github.com/oldfartdeveloper/list-view/blob/install-ember-cli-0.0.40/README.md)** under **Installation**.